# Building a canvas template in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm attempting to build a golf game tracking program that uses a canvas to hold an arranged set of buttons and databound items for each player. Because the number of people in a game is dynamic, I need to be able to build the canvases on the fly and bind them on the fly as well. the problem I'm having is setting up the databinding. If I attempt to bind in code then the text for the binding (text={Binding}) always comes out as though it were a string literal instead of an actual binding. To get around this I attempted to build a template of the canvas, but I can't find a way to actually apply the template to a new canvas as I build out new players.

So with all that in mind, what is the best way to either A) build a template canvas with all my controls so I can just copy and bind to each player, or B) build the text bindings dynamically without having to resort to XAML?

Edit: The following was added for clarification on how I'm creating a textblock.

```
TextBlock newBlock = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "{Binding}",
            FontSize = 42,
            DataContext = Player.SomeStat,
            Name = Player.PlayerName ,

        };
```

The value shown on the screen for the textblock (instead of what it should be) is: {Binding}

Comment: Can you post example? Should be Text="{Binding}" and not text={Binding} (the later won't compile)

Comment: I can add an example when I get home. I do have Text="{Binding}", but posted away from the project so I was simply stating that I had tried to provide the supposedly correct value properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Binding in code you need to go some extra steps:

```
object myDataObject = DataContext;
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myBinding.Path="."; // not sure if required
newBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to bind to the datacontext of the Control instance your code lives in...

```
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Foo"));
textBlock.DataContext = this.DataContext;
```